# Sizing a UICollectionView to fit its contents within an AutoLayout View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a UIView that I'm using as a footer for a UITableView.  Within this UIView Is a UIWebView and UICollectionView.  They are laid out as follows:

```
H:|[webview]|
H:|[collection]|
V:|[webview]-8-[collection(10@1)]|
```

This is being done via IB but this indicates the constraints that are in place.

I'd like to have the webview sized to it's contents (I have that working) and the collection as well sized to it's contents.  I'd like the overall UIView they are contained in sized to fit all of this without scrolling as it's contained in a tableview which handles it's own scrolling.

I can not seem to get the collection to size itself larger than the 10 points that the constraint has.  In addition the constraint system demands that something have a height.

How do I get to my goal of a view sized to fit both subviews which are in turn sized to fit their contents?   I have tried adjusting the frame on the collectionview in the sizeToFit method for the overall view but I believe the constraint system is undoing that.

Comment: Have you solved this meanwhile? I have a problem quite like yours. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Collection views have no intrinsic content size associated with them. There is currently no way to achieve what you are looking for.

If you feel that this is something that would be useful to have, please file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com (log in with your developer account).